# Enabling CDN to kubernetes backend through backendconfig doesn't allow custom host and path rules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Not able to add custom path rules lo Google CDN Loadbalancer

Despite some minor issues like address flapping between custom ingress controller IP and reserved CDN IP, we are implementing CDN for our GKE hosted app following this tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cdn-backendconfig)

Almost everything is fine, but when trying to add some path rules, via k8s manifest or Google loadbalancer UI, they take no effect at all, in fact, in the UI case, the rules disappear after 2 minutes...

Any thoughts?

Comment: As a piece of cake, this is working: 
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cdn-staging-ingress-engine2
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "cdn-test-address-engine2"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cdntest.staging2.beabloo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: cdn-staging-engine2-service
          servicePort: 80

Comment: But this is not:
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cdn-staging-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "cdn-test-address"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cdntest.staging
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app
        backend:
          serviceName: cdn-staging-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: statics-bucket
          servicePort: 80

Answer (score 1):

Try using "kubectl replace" when dealing with ingress manifest. Google Cloud does not allow updates to ingress after it is created. So in Kubernetes it might look like you make changes but they will not get applied in Google Cloud.

Comment: Hi Vasily,

First of all: Thank you for answering.
I have tried deleting the original ingress and applying a new manifest with all required paths, but it does not work, by the way, I have tried your suggestion (replace) and it neither works.

Answer (score 0):

Using kubectl describe, in the Events section, I found this warning:
  Warning  Translate  114s (x32 over 48m)   loadbalancer-controller   error while evaluating the ingress spec: service "xxx-staging/statics-bucket" is type "ClusterIP", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"
So, this is the problem, I will try to change this and post here the resolution.